# Is there a JPA feature to merge based on non Id fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

A service I am building receives data from an external system that come with the vendor's "external ID". When I save this data in our database, I assign an auto-generated ID to it too:

```
@Entity
public class Content {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private Long externalId;

 // many other fields
}
```

When the external system resends the data for the same content (with the same external ID), it is deserialized into a detached Content POJO:

```
Content c = deserialize(json);
```

Is there something like `EntityManager.merge` that can load and update the corresponding row from the database using the `externalId` field, rather than the `id` field?

Comment: I don't think there is. You will have to look up your entity via a createQuery probably; that might impose an index creation on the externalId. Nevertheless interesting question IMO

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but if the external client does not know your id you have to use a query to get the entity (you actually only need the entity's id). Once you have the id you can set it on the detached entity and do a merge.

Hope this helps.